# I am currently working on a tutorial in LUA. How do I add sound to my Lua code?

Tags: audio, keypad

Newbie here currently working on a soundpad tutorial in Lua code. I seem to be stuck at inserting the sound. this is my first attempt at coding. any help is really appreciated.

```
 local sampleNames = {
    {"kick","snare","",""},
    {"hat","","",""},
    {"","","",""},
    {"","","",""}
```

}

```
function eventChannel1(sender, event)

    if event.ButtonDown then -- was the event caused by a button being pressed?

        local sampleName = sampleNames[event.Y][event.X] -- get the name of the sample from        our table
    local sample = gdt.ROM.User.AudioSamples[sampleName] -- load that sample from our assets

    if sample ~= nil then -- is the sample we tried to load anything but nil?
        gdt.AudioChip0:Play(sample, (event.X + event.Y * 4)) -- play the sample we loaded
    end

end
```

end

I tried everything the tutorial told me to do. I expect to hear my keys make a "kick", "snare" and "hat" sound.

Comment: Tell us the URL of the tutorial you're following.  //  Show us your [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) results, including the `print()`'s you inserted within each `if`, and the debug output they displayed. Figure out if you actually get a button event; view `.X` and `.Y`. Then figure out if even the simplest call to `Play()` produces any audible sound.

Comment: https://docs.retrogadgets.game/cookbook/01-soundboard.html

Comment: Im not sure what debugging means. I'm just starting to learn the coding terminolgy a well. Thanks!

Comment: When you see an underlined word on a web page, try to [click the link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) so it will take you to a helpful tutorial.